# Help identifying LEGO sets - Star Wars?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

My toddler inherited a bunch of LEGO pieces that all seem to be Star Wars.  I was able to determine about 1/2 of the bunch were 4 Microfighter sets since some parts are unique.  I am stuck identifying the rest.  I have “two” very unique items but just can’t seem to place them... !

One item is a dome with a hinge and it has ‘paneling’ Design but it is not like the domes I’ve seen on tie-fighter sets, the other are sticks w/ a 1x2 on one end and a circle on other that are about 3.5” long.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome Court!

Looks like  part# *<strike>42445 Bar 12L with 1 x 2 Plate End Solid Studs and 1 x 1 Round Plate End.</strike>*

Part# *99784 Bar 12L with 1 x 2 Plate End Hollow Studs and 1 x 1 Round Plate End*.

[image: ![enter image description here]

and

*part #50747pb06 Windscreen 6 x 6 x 3 Canopy Half Sphere with Dual 2 Fingers and SW Tie-Fighter Pattern.*

[image]

From 
*[Set #9492 TIE Fighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9492-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.

[image]

Later!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!  I knew this would work, these pieces were way too specific.  You are awesome!

Comment: Just a subtle correction: these are 99784, Bar 12L with 1 x 2 Plate End Hollow Studs and 1 x 1 Round Plate End.

Comment: Thx Aziraphale!